# How do I move this ribbon to the bottom right of the page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

The ribbon itself is shamelessly stolen from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342015/32679):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{calc}

    \newcommand{\stripskip}{5}
    \newcommand{\stripwidth}{3}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        overlay, 
        remember picture,
        legend/.style={|<->|, gray, font = {\ttfamily}},
        confidential/.style={anchor=center, rotate = -45, font={\sffamily\scshape}}
    ]
        \coordinate (A) at ($ (current page.north east) + (-\stripskip,0) $);
        \coordinate (A') at ($(A) + (-\stripwidth,0) $);

        \coordinate (B) at ($ (current page.north east) + (0,-\stripskip) $);
        \coordinate (B') at ($(B) + (0,-\stripwidth) $);

        \fill [red] (A) -- (A') -- (B') -- (B) -- cycle;

        \coordinate (tempA) at ($(A)!.5!(A')$);
        \coordinate (tempB) at ($(B)!.5!(B')$);

        \node [confidential](text) at ($(tempA)!.5!(tempB)$) {Confidential};

        \draw [legend] ($(A) + (0,-.75ex)$) -- ($(A') + (0,-.75ex)$) node [below, midway] {\textbackslash stripwidth};
        \draw [legend] ($(A) + (0,-.75ex)$) -- ($(current page.north east) + (0,-.75ex)$) node [below, midway] {\textbackslash stripskip};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \centering Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

I apologize for this simple question, but TikZ is still black magic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change coordinates from `current page.north.east` to `current page.south east` and correctly add distance `\stripskip` ....

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{calc}

    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \newcommand{\stripskip}{5}
    \newcommand{\stripwidth}{3}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        overlay,
        remember picture,
        legend/.style={|<->|, gray, font = {\ttfamily}},
        confidential/.style={anchor=center, rotate = 45, % <-- changed angle
                             font={\sffamily\scshape}}
                        ]
        \coordinate (A) at ($ (current page.south east) + (-\stripskip,0) $);% <-- changed coordinate from 'north' to south'
        \coordinate (A') at ($(A) + (-\stripwidth,0) $);

        \coordinate (B) at ($ (current page.south east) + (0,\stripskip) $);% <-- changed coordinate from 'north' to south' and sign for \stripskip
        \coordinate (B') at ($(B) + (0,\stripwidth) $);% <-- changed sign for \stripskip 

        \fill [red,semitransparent] (A) -- (A') -- (B') -- (B) -- cycle;

        \coordinate (tempA) at ($(A)!.5!(A')$);
        \coordinate (tempB) at ($(B)!.5!(B')$);

        \node [confidential](text) at ($(tempA)!.5!(tempB)$) {Confidential};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! One of these days, I really should get around the TikZ basics ...